# Share dialog posts do not include query string of deep link to facebook iframe page tab

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-sharer

I am attempting to use the standard Facebook share button to share a deep link into my iframe page tab of the form:

https://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=**any_string_here**

where app_data content is a deep link relative path into my iframe page tab app content 
(e.g. /path/to/page_that_I_shared_from).

Just to be clear, there is a Share button on my iframe app page, and I am trying to generate the link back to that page to be shared.

I place the absolute URL above into the data-href parameter per the Share Dialog documentation, and when I click the Share button, the url in the share dialog is of the form:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=my_app_id&sdk=joey&u=url_encoded_version_of_the_absolute_url_above&display=popup

but when the post is rendered, the query string is stripped completely.

Note that if I use a non-Facebook URL, the query string is preserved.

I do notice that app_id parameter in the share dialog URL - perhaps the fact that this is coming from inside the page tab iframe makes a difference.

Initial testing with the feed dialog looks promising, but I'd like to use the share button since it provides more flexibility as to the destination of the post.

Comment: I've tested this just now and it is working for me. Are you using a button like this: `<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testing-stuff/738439836185066?id=738439836185066&amp;sk=app_402263436574179&amp;app_data=test" data-type="button_count"></div>` check that the app_data part is included and the & is escaped etc.

Comment: Also, remember that the app_data is sent to your iFrame as an encoded HTTP post in the signed_request - you can't just grab it from the GET parameters.

Comment: Yeah I know about pulling the app_data from the signed request. I saw the sk= syntax elsewhere but assumed it was old. I will try and encode the ampersands and see if it helps.

Comment: My app was sandboxed so I thought that might make a difference but I made it visible and there was no change in behavior.

Comment: I generated the following link and the behavior was no different:

`https://www.facebook.com/pages/WesTestPage/167262220121649?id=167262220121649&amp;sk=app_1380168878891178&amp;app_data=test`

The link that is rendered in the post is only for the page and doesn't include any of the query string.

Comment: Can you paste the HTML for the share button?

Comment: `<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<%= share_url %>" data-type="button"></div>`


`<%= share_url %>` is interpolated into the HTML.

Comment: The deep link that I generate for the page tab iframe app. is fine. I can copy and paste it in a separate tab and it works as advertised. The share dialog appears to contain the entire URL. But the link that shows up in the share dialog that is ultimately presented in the post does not include the query string.

Comment: I included your button on my tab like this:

`<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/WesTestPage/167262220121649?id=167262220121649&amp;sk=app_1380168878891178&amp;app_data=test" data-type="button_count"></div>`

When I click the button, it shares to my wall - you can see the link is set correctly in this screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/cGwCjxG.png

When I follow that link it takes me to your app on your page and the URL has the app data - you can see that in this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/y7vf9WC.png

Comment: Well, shit :). If I hard code that link it appears to work. Something must be happening on the interpolation???

Thanks, David for spending the time.

Comment: Haha, no problem. Hope you fix it.

Comment: Geez, how embarrassing. Rails auto-escapes the HTML, so I need to pass <%= raw(share_url) %>. Still working out the kinks, but I can make it post a link into the app. 

I will post the final solution once I have it.

Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Closer. My app_data parameter is a relative URL with it's own query string. It appears that only the ?= portion is being included in the shared link, but nothing afterward (starting with the first &).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution was to generate the link like so:

`https://www.facebook.com/pages/<page id>/<page id>?id=<page_id>&amp;sk=app_<FB_app_ id>&amp;app_data=<deep link>`

where deep_link is a relative URL with a query string that starts with a '?' and has the '&' characters replaced with '|' characters (poor man's encoding that I decode on the way in).

I saw several suggestions (mostly here on SO) to double or even triple encode the app_data URL - none of these worked, and usually they resulted in links that could not be posted by the sharer.php script.

Comment: Later, I discovered that these links, while they work, do have a limit on the size of the app_data parameter, per: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1417937768438869